# Haskell Servant: Construct URL from API

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, servant

Suppose we have this simple API:

```hs
type FooAPI
   = "foo" 
  :> QueryParam "age" Int 
  :> Get '[PlainText] Text
```

Is there a way to link type-level `servant`'s API with a function that will generate URL for it? Like

```hs
someMagicFunction :: Proxy api -> SomeTypeFamily api
someMagicFunction = ?

generateURL :: Maybe Int -> Text
generateURL = someMagicFunction (Proxy @FooAPI)

>>> generateURL (Just 42)
"https://somehost/foo?age=42"
>>> generateURL Nothing
"https://somehost/foo"
```

I want to increase type-safety of URL generation so if I'll add some new parameter to `FooAPI` it will immediately appear in the type of `generateURL` and my code will not compile without editing the calls of `generateURL`.

I'm aware of `servant-client` library and I know that `client` function does somewhat similar but I couldn't figure out how to use this library in my case.

Comment: It is possible but would require writing lots of instances.  I had a comment here or on reddit calling out the specific class, but suffice to say when I looked for Servant 0.14  it was not a cheap job and not yet done for you in the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that [`Servant.Links`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.18.3/docs/Servant-Links.html) is exactly what you are looking for.

In particular, in your case I would use [`allLinks`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.18.3/docs/Servant-Links.html#v:allLinks) to generate a `Link` corresponding to the URL piece containing the path and query parameters:

```hs
>>> linkURI $ allLinks (Proxy @FooAPI) Nothing
foo
>>> linkURI $ allLinks (Proxy @FooAPI) (Just 18)
foo?age=18
```

Then I would transform the generated `Link` into an `URI` where I would specify required scheme and hostname. Here's a fully working module:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators    #-}

import           Data.Proxy
import           Data.Text     (Text)
import           Network.URI
import           Servant.API
import           Servant.Links

type FooAPI
   = "foo"
  :> QueryParam "age" Int
  :> Get '[PlainText] Text

generateURL :: Maybe Int -> String
generateURL age = show uri
  { uriScheme = "https:"
  , uriAuthority = Just nullURIAuth
    { uriRegName = "somehost" }
  , uriPath = "/" <> uriPath uri
  }
  where
    uri = linkURI link
    link = allLinks (Proxy @FooAPI) age
```

And demonstration:

```hs
>>> generateURL (Just 42)
"https://somehost/foo?age=42"
>>> generateURL Nothing
"https://somehost/foo"
```